# Updating iTunes for Windows XP failed; no longer functions

Tags: itunes, software-update, windows

I am getting this error message when I try to open iTunes:

iTunes.exe - Entry Point Not Found. The procedure entry point A VCFAssetCreateWithByteStreamAndOptions could not be located in the dynamic link library AVFoundationCF.dll

When I click OK, it states that "iTunes was not installed correctly. Please reinstall iTunes. Error 7 (Windows error 127)."

I have tried to do the fix but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have tried to do the fix but it does not work?" Have you tried reinstalling it?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be most easily resolved by re-downloading the full installer from [apple.com/itunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) and running it.

Note that you don't actually have to fill in an e-mail address in order to download it. Uncheck the boxes, click the Download button, and it should start within a few short seconds.

After the download completes, run the installer and try to open iTunes again.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you have a message error like  “iPodService Module has encountered a problem and needs to close.” try this  : http://www.techyv.com/questions/error-installing-itunes-windows-xp#comment-48393